# Feign AuthRequest

Tags: java, spring, feign

In my first developmentstep i logged in with my FeignClient.
That works well.

```
public class FeignClientConfiguration  {
```

public String userkrz = "abc";
  public String password = "123xy456";

```
@Bean // ({"authBean"})
public BasicAuthRequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor() {
    return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor( userkrz, password );
}
```

}

```
public class FeignClientConfiguration  {
```

public String userkrz = "abc";
  public String password = "123xy456";

```
@Bean // ({"authBean"})
public BasicAuthRequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor() {
    return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor( userkrz, password );
}
```

}

But the client authorized by starting the client and I dont know how I authorized me later.
I would set the credentials concerning the runtime.